# Determine a so fB is asymptotically faster than fA

Tags: functions

I got those two functions:

$f_A(n) = 4f(\frac{n}{2}) + \mathcal{O}(n^2);$

$f_B(n) = af(\frac{n}{4}) + \mathcal{O}(n^2).$

So with the master theorem, for $f_A$, I got $1 \implies \mathcal{O}(n^2\log(n))$;

and, for $\frac{f_B}{16} < 1, \implies \mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

How do I determine $a$ so $f_B$ is asymptotically faster than $f_A$ with the master theorem?